# Changing base url depending on preprocessor macro value

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a project with a few schemes, one for EA, Staged, and Production.

I want to be able to set my base url based on what build configuration I am running.

```
#if defined PRODUCTION
#define BASE_URL [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.production.com/"]

#elif defined STAGED
#define BASE_URL [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.staged.com/"]

#else
#define BASE_URL [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.ea.com/"]
#endif
```

Is there a way to set preprocessor macros in order to define the values of PRODUCTION and STAGED, I'm guessing it's somewhere in the build settings of my target. And would this be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually store my URLs in a NSObject class (Aptly named URLHub) with class methods like so;

```
+(NSString *)Login
{
    NSString *url;

    if (developmentMode) {
        url = @"https://dev.mycoolwebservice/api/login";
    } else {
        url = @"https://mycoolwebservice/api/login";
    }

    return url;
}
```

Then wherever I need to use that url I can grab easily;

```
#import "URLHub.h"

NSString *url = [URLHub Login];
```

This approach makes it super simple to update urls throught the entire app since they are all stored in the same place.

In this example to switch over to development urls I just need to flip one BOOL and every url app-wide changes. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve the functionality, though only one to my knowledge that works with schemes.

The first option, is outside the scope of schemes, and works with the targets preprocessor macros - for development, DEBUG is set to 1, and release, DEBUG is set to 0.  You can add as many macros as you would like - to do so, go to your targets "Build Settings", and search for "Preprocessor Macros" - it's pretty much right there.

To work with schemes, you would need to add an environment variable to your scheme:

Edit Scheme -> Add an environment variable.

To access the environment variable you would need to do:

```
[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment] objectForKey:@"myKey"]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had found the Preprocessor Macros in build setting right after posting the question. I didn't actually have to make a environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

In the "Other C Flags" build setting, put `-DPRODUCTION` and `-DSTAGED`, in the different build configurations. (You will need to create those extra build configurations, of course.)