# How to organize the API Url's in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, url, code-organization

I am trying to organize all my API url's in a single file,
what I am doing is I created a header file and added the following lines

```
#define LOGIN_URL           @"http://192.168.100.100/api/login"
#define SIGNUP_URL          @"http://192.168.100.100/api/signup"
#define PRODUCTS_URL        @"http://192.168.100.100/api/products"
#define EMPLOYEE_URL        @"http://192.168.100.100/api/employee"
#define GET_PRODUCTS_URL    @"http://192.168.100.100/api/getproducts"
#define CLIENTS_URL         @"http://192.168.100.100/api/clients"
```

Here the `base url` is `http://192.168.100.100/` which will keep on changing, I always have to find and replace the IP Address.
Is there any better ways to organize API Url's?

Comment: Here's a similar question with good solutions.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448896/changing-base-url-depending-on-preprocessor-macro-value

Comment: See: [Build a list of constants variable from other constants](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10055187)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hey you may organise all your API Url's by using the following code

```
#define SITE_URL(url) @"http://192.168.100.100/api" url

#define LOGIN_URL           SITE_URL("/login")
#define SIGNUP_URL          SITE_URL("/signup")

#define PRODUCTS_URL        SITE_URL("/products")
#define EMPLOYEE_URL        SITE_URL("/employee")
#define GET_PRODUCTS_URL    SITE_URL("/getproducts")
#define CLIENTS_URL         SITE_URL("/clients")
```

Comment: I'd put it back the way it was. The IP address needs to be easily changed (for failover). Who cares if parts of the URL are similar?

Comment: @MarcusAdams my url has the word `api` so it does work for me.

Answer (score 6):

I personally like to use constants over `#define`

Here is how I would do what you're trying to do.

**MyAppConstants.h**

```
extern NSString * const  kLOGIN_URL;  
extern NSString * const  kSIGNUP_URL; 
extern NSString * const  kPRODUCTS_URL;
extern NSString * const  kEMPLOYEE_URL;
extern NSString * const  kGET_PRODUCTS_URL;
extern NSString * const  kCLIENTS_URL;
```

**MyAppConstants.m**

```
NSString * const  kLOGIN_URL           = @"/login"
NSString * const  kSIGNUP_URL          = @"/signup"
NSString * const  kPRODUCTS_URL        = @"/products"
NSString * const  kEMPLOYEE_URL        = @"/employee"
NSString * const  kGET_PRODUCTS_URL    = @"/getproducts"
NSString * const  kCLIENTS_URL         = @"/clients"
```

Then when I use the constants I would do something like...

```
NSURL *loginURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseUrl stringByAppendingString:kLOGIN_URL]];
```

Comment: Is there any issue in using #define?

Comment: I think so, check out this post @icodebuster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-in-c